# Mongodb compass Insert not permitted while document contains errors

Tags: mongodb, compass

I'm trying to insert some data in the compass
and the formwork shows to me as below:

```
/** 
* Paste one or more documents here
*/
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6065bca3dad082deb74c05bc"
    }
}
```

I think maybe I should input in this way, but it dosen't work:

```
/** 
* Paste one or more documents here
*/
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6065bca3dad082deb74c05bc"
    }

    "username":{
         "wpx"
    }
}
```

How should I do, thanks!

Comment: See [Insert Documents - Compass](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/documents/insert/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a comma is missing between the keys. Also, there must be some value given to "wpx" key.

so your document should look like..

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6065bca3dad082deb74c05bc"
    },
    "username":{
         "wpx":""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The document should be inside the [] square bracket and all the documents should be separated by (,) a comma.